# PFSense routing

Tags: networking, router, pfsense

I have PFSense on the following: 192.168.1.1 with machines on the 192.168.1.1/24.

I would like this network to be able to access the 192.168.2.2 network. The WAN on the pfsense is currently 192.168.2.223 and the 192.168.2.0/24 pfsense router with internet access is on 192.168.2.254.

I'm trying without any success in getting the 192.168.1.1/24 network dial out to the 192.168.2.0/24 or the internet.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You **should not** have an **Upstream Gateway in you LAN**. The Upstream Gateway should be configured in your **WAN interface** (in this case would be **192.168.2.254** which is, I guess, your internet provider). Looks like you have a wrong network configuration. You should design a simple network diagram with the IP addresses of every device for more info.